# Replying to an answer with a picture

Tags: discussion, answers, images

I would like to reply to an answer I got on my question with a few pictures, essentially discussing the answer I got, as I don't know if it's wrong or I'm using the equations provided wrong.

First of all, is it even okay to discuss an answer?
Second, how would I reply to a picture? Would I put the picture on another site and provide a link to it or should there be (or there is and I just don't know about it) a way to post a picture in the comments?

The question in question (lol punz) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148823/mapping-coordinates-on-a-plane-tangent-to-a-sphere-into-cartesian-coordinates-in).

Comment: I would say you need help in person.

Comment: @WillJagy I would love to get real-time help over something like Skype. However the reason I came here is because it's the best thing I could think of.

Comment: Re: *First of all, is it even okay to discuss an answer?* That's what comments are for. *Is there a way to post a picture in the comments?* Yes. Simply start new post where you include the picture. Do not submit the post, but copy the link generated in the post. See also the older posts: [Is it possible to insert an image in comments? if the answer is “yes”, then how?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16445/) and [How can I insert a picture/graphic on an answer or comment?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16323/).

Comment: Another point.  This is NOT a discussion site.  Sometimes a brief back-and-forth in the comments is seen, but if it gets too long the software will tell you to go to chat.